# NextJS custom _error page can't catch error details for server side errors in the production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, sentry

I am trying to catch NextJS serverside errors and flush the error messages to the sentry.

It is flushing messages without error details.

Here is the `getServerSideProps` error that I use try-catch block to catch an error in a nextjs page.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => {
    try {
        throw new Error(`Server side error has been occured`)
        return {
            props: {
// SSR props
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
    return { props: {} }
}
```

Here is the `_error.tsx` page implementation:

```
    import * as Sentry from "@sentry/nextjs"
    import NextErrorComponent, {ErrorProps as NextErrorProps} from "next/error"
    import {NextPageContext} from "next"
    // import envs from 'helpers/envs';
    
    export type ErrorPageProps = {
        err: Error
        statusCode: number
    }
    
    export type ErrorProps = {
        isReadyToRender: boolean
    } & NextErrorProps
    
    const ErrorPage = (props: ErrorPageProps): JSX.Element => {
        const {statusCode, err} = props
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger

        // the problem is in here. err comes as undefined.
        if (err) {
            Sentry.captureException(err)
        }
    
        return (
            <p>
                {statusCode ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server` : "An error occurred on client"}
            </p>
        )
    }
    
    ErrorPage.getInitialProps = async (props: NextPageContext): Promise<ErrorProps> => {
        const {res, err, asPath} = props
        console.log(err)
    
        const errorInitialProps: ErrorProps = (await NextErrorComponent.getInitialProps({
            res,
            err
        } as NextPageContext)) as ErrorProps
    
        errorInitialProps.isReadyToRender = true
    
        if (res?.statusCode === 404) {
            return {statusCode: 404, isReadyToRender: true}
        }
    
        if (err) {
            Sentry.captureException(err)
            await Sentry.flush(2000)
            return errorInitialProps
        }
    
        Sentry.captureException(new Error(`_error.js getInitialProps missing data at path: ${asPath}`))
        await Sentry.flush(2000)
    
        return errorInitialProps
    }
    
    export default ErrorPage
```

How can I get error details from SSR and send to the sentry?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt anything will be running after `throw`. Your `return` statements might not run as expected. You can try returning proper props from inside the catch

Comment: I tried to return error as a prop but it didn't help. Do you have a working code example? @TusharShahi

Comment: The `_error` page is only used in production (you’ll get an error with the call stack in development mode). Have you tried running the app in production mode?

Comment: The main problem is that I am not able get sentry messages in the production mode. The Question is about this actually. After it is built in production mode it doesn't throw any message. I can catch error but sentry doesn't flush the messages. @juliomalves

Comment: Is `ErrorPage.getInitialProps` running when the error gets triggered in the page?

Comment: What do you mean actually? Could you illustrate this? Do you mean in th _error.tsx page or next page? @juliomalves

Comment: When you access the page that throws the error, does `ErrorPage.getInitialProps` get to run at all?

Comment: Yes correct it is running but sentry isnt flushing the message @juliomalves